# Tag Request for 3D Printing: [Fusion360] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think that there should be a Fusion360 tag. It would be useful for Fusion360-related questions. I was making a question about Fusion360, but then I realized that there was not a Fusion360 tag. There is a TinkerCAD tag, which is a similar CAD system, but no Fusion360 tag. Please make this tag, as it will be very useful for Fusion360 questions.

Answer (score 4):

Write your question, and we can add a tag to it. Tags which have no questions associated with them become removed automatically.

Comment: [This question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/what-is-the-point-of-diminishing-returns-on-the-stl-refinement-level-in-fusion-3) could use the [tag:Fusion360] tag

Comment: @ifconfig, added the tag